# avoiding alias at command prompt

Tags: linux, mysql, bash, alias

I have following alias and it is working as expected.

```
alias mysql='LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local//mysql/lib/:/usr/local//mysql/lib//mysql /usr/local//mysql/bin//mysql'
```

My question is there are a few other commands like mysqldump , mysqladmin those needs to be linked as well. How to I let the shell prompt know where to look for mysql command without using alias?

This is an issue only on one server where cluster is installed. On all other servers I can type "mysql" or "mysqladmin".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the systemwide or userspecific configuration of your system to include the relevant paths in the `LD_LIBRARAY_PATH` and `PATH` environment variables.

E.g. for the user-specific variant, put something like

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/mysql/lib/:/usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql 
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

into your `~/.profile` file.

This will add these directories to the search path for libraries and executable files.